# Monitoring changes in SQL db using Java

Tags: java, mysql, sql, monitoring

I want to check for changes in a SQL database but not sure what the best approach would be.

Currently what I do is I create an Object with column (key, value) information and store that into an ArrayList. I then copy that ArrayList and make a new one called my "cache".

Now, this is what I'm doing: every X ms I am grabbing all the data from the SQL db and then comparing that to my cached local copy. If there is anything different e.g. a value has been updated, inserted or deleted, I have a listener to notify me.

Is this a bad approach? Should I be doing a "SELECT * FROM table" query or is there another way I can get the information I want. I also want to be able to see the specific data that has been modified e.g. the row, the column and value.

Note: The database is generic.

Comment: If you want to do something when data in a DB is changed, you usually code the logic in a DB `TRIGGER`. Polling the whole DB from the Java client to keep track of changes is going to be _hugely_ inefficient. Is the DB accessible to clients that you do not have control over?

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database) are you using? Postgres? Oracle? Both offer features for client notification through JDBC

Comment: @MickMnemonic It's a database hosted at a remote location. The access is being done on a server that connects to that database. I need some way to monitor changes on the database so I can update certain things on the server. How do I use triggers in my case?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I'm currently using a MariaDB/MySQL however I want to write this so it works with any generic database.

Comment: There is no "generic" way to do that (at least no _efficient_ generic way)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Then is the method I'm currently doing suitable?